# Adding form fields and encrypt PDF (in one go)

Tags: itext, openpdf

I want to add several (acro) form fields to a pdf and afterwards encrypt it.
Each single operation does work however if I do both I get the following error:

> Content was already written to the output.

The Code in the PdfStamper checks (`stamper.isContentWritten()`) whether something was already written to the body, which obviously was the case when adding the form field annotation. Found the following code:

```
if (!annot.isUsed()) {
    annot.setUsed();
    addToBody(annot, annot.getIndirectReference());
}
```

Is there a way to do both with an existing instance of the PdfWriter/Stamper or do I have write out the enriched document and re-initialize the itext/openPDF Processor again to encrypt it?

Comment: Have you set the encryption as early as possible after instantiating the stamper?

Comment: Yes you were right (as usual :-) I changed the order and got it working. Thanks. If you add this as an answer i'll accept!